# Get union type from indexed object values

Tags: typescript

Say I have an indexed type:

```
type X = {
 a: 'A',
 b: 'B'
}
```

is it possible to get (derived) from it:

```
type V = 'A' | 'B'
```

not using explicit method like:

```
type V = X['a'] | X['b']
```

What I want is something like `keyof` (for getting keys union type), but for values.

Comment: Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393730/typescript-string-literal-union-type-from-enum

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use a type query with the result of `keyof`:

```
type V = X[keyof X]
```

Generally a type query will return a union of all possible field types, so `X['a'] | X['b']` is the same as `X['a' | 'b']`. This is why `X[keyof X]` works, as `keyof` will return a union of string literal types representing all keys in the object.

Answer (score 45):

I realize this has already been answered, but if you are looking for a way to narrow your union to **actual** values instead of primitives and you are working with immutable state, you can do this:

```js
const X = {
  a: 'A', 
  b: 'B'
  // mark properties as readonly, otherwise string type inferred 
} as const

type XValues = typeof X[keyof typeof X]

// "A" | "B
```

Alternatively, if you are working with both mutable and immutable copies, creating a separate readonly type could be useful:

```
const X = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B'
} 

type X = Readonly<typeof X>

type XValues = keyof X  

// "A" | "B
```

Comment: Yeah, it should go to separate answer but it is indeed exactly what I'm looking for! Quite neat trick with `as const`. Thanks!

Comment: The alternative solution didn't work.

Comment: Interesting, here is a playground example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAGjAvDA3gKBjAhgLhgcgEF8AaDGAIz3wCF80BfGNNKATwAcBTeJGAJS5YAJuAA2bADztuIAGbwAfCxk84ANSxiArlwh8A1lzbzeQA

Answer (score 3):

In case someone wants to do this for a union of types, instead of just one type, this works perfectly:

```
type allSubTypesOfUnionType<T> = T extends any ? T[keyof T] : never
```

So if you have a union of 2 types:

```
type cheese = {
  name: string
  holes: number
}
type pizza = {
  slices: number
  isPepperoni: boolean
}
type yellowFood = cheese | pizza
```

You can then create a type that extracts all the sub-types as a union:

```
type possibleTypesOfYellowFood  = allSubTypesOfUnionType<yellowFood>
// types is: number | string | boolean
```

This was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52221718/14266931) that did the same but for keys instead of sub-types.