# Get type from nested object as type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get only the number keys as an type?

```
export const messageTypes = {
  ABLEHNUNG_ECON: {
    56: {
      message: "Zählpunkt nicht gefunden",
      event: function () {},
    },
    181: {
      message: "Gemeinschafts-ID nicht vorhanden",
      event: function () {},
    },
  },
  ZUSTIMMUNG_ECON: {
    175: {
      message: "Zustimmung erteilt",
      event: function () {},
    },
  },
  ANTWORT_ECON: {
    99: {
      message: "Meldung erhalten",
      event: function () {},
    },
  },
  ABSCHLUSS_ECON: {
    message: "Abschluss erhalten",
    event: async function (userId: string) {
      await sendNotification(userId, this.message);
    },
  },
};
```

If i do `type MessageT = typeof messageTypes` i get the whole object, but is it somehow possible to get only the numbers?

Result should be: `type ResponseCodesT = 56 | 181 | 175 | 99`

Comment: `ABSCHLUSS_ECON` doesn't have any numeric key inside it, is this intentional or typo?

Comment: @Cerberus its not typo, its intentional. However, i could technically add an random code in this case, but i first ask if its possible now how it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using a little keyof trick ([Typescript: keyof typeof union between object and primitive is always never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221574/typescript-keyof-typeof-union-between-object-and-primitive-is-always-never)):

```js
export const messageTypes = {
  ABLEHNUNG_ECON: {
    56: {
      message: "Zählpunkt nicht gefunden",
      event: function () {},
    },
    181: {
      message: "Gemeinschafts-ID nicht vorhanden",
      event: function () {},
    },
  },
  ZUSTIMMUNG_ECON: {
    175: {
      message: "Zustimmung erteilt",
      event: function () {},
    },
  },
  ANTWORT_ECON: {
    99: {
      message: "Meldung erhalten",
      event: function () {},
    },
  },
};

type AllUnionMemberKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type MessageCode = AllUnionMemberKeys<(typeof messageTypes)[keyof typeof messageTypes]>;

// type MessageCode = 56 | 181 | 175 | 99
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLbFaghgc2ABUBPMbOAXjgG8BYAKDjgEEAhAGQFEAJAOQCqfAOIB9LgGEA8nwBctRs2YBWAGzz6TJcyw4CweQCIAWgBOAFgBswAV2QBreMgCWCc-EIAzOwBNgyQwAaRW04YAA3fxh5b2QEGGcUOAAKAEpaAF9grWYskOYARgAOAo18pV08QiNhYCxnNDdcTxhUAFoASQAROBc3eHDoc1xkPwDs0LDI5Gi4WPjE5BT0mjycuDXcibhjAQBlIg6AWSOhMUkZMvWCgHZlK8nK-SNjG3RnDAw7fDDYYGdLDAguVmBEojE7AskmlMtstiFNqw+EQAOpSABKRHE0jkCnWAE58Q9Qk9qnBDEdgJYfN9fsNAf5getQdNZvMEtCVoj4Vo1hkANyMRgwMjAViWSwCFwoSkYABGwCgAGlgCRUAAeIgAPiocCIYRAMH8PlQcBGJDgAH44PZVRBPHq4PJkGCoIKGKBILA4CLyHBKXpCBIIH5dSwJVLFrKFcrVRrkr7gPa4KTiKLUKkANq2kjJxPJ1OkcioAC6Wv5QA)

I intentionally left out ABSCHLUSS_ECON as an exercise for the reader :) (Hint: the union will include `message` and `event`).

Comment: Could you explain why is `AllUnionMemberKeys` required ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler see the linked question for details. in short, keyof X | Y produces never if X and Y have no properties in common, while the conditional helps because it distributes the union first and then unions the keys.