# How to get a union type of classes in an object

Tags: typescript

I have a constant object like this:

```
class A {}
class B {}

const X = {
 a: A,
 b: B
} as const
```

How can I get a union type of the object values `A | B` (without duplicating code)?

e.g. I want to achieve this:

```
// I need
type XUnion = A | B;
// so that this works
const bar: XUnion = new A();
```

I have tried to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044023/get-union-type-from-indexed-object-values), but it does not work:

```
type XValues = typeof X[keyof typeof X];
// now XValues = typeof A | typeof B

const foo: XValues = new A();
//    ^^^ compile error: 
// Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'XValues'.
// Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'typeof B'.
```

Here is a link to the example in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=30&pln=9&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8C%20BYAUKSMBCjVvWAHsA7CAF2gA1oBeRdaMALjgBpGAjV7dJJmMTLl06APRjo5AJ4AHAKZEAZnGgAfKXMUreaGQuoA1MCACu8mPX3bqAbQDW86cs0KXVALoBuQqQrQlIiJWKmMzCzpoEnkAdzgACgBKHwI0CWgASSj5eQATdGtqAFUSAEtSSPgNbBT0iCIpAAswSnJG0pgYogAnewhfYWhOMG6QkvKSSOi42CSUoA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

I found the type we were looking for: [InstanceType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype).

```js
type XValues = InstanceType<typeof X[keyof typeof X]>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEBBeBvAvqSsECFUZEwHsA7GAF3gA14BeVUeKALiQBpGAjVnUNJhGFIVQoAPRj45AJ4AHAKZEAZkngAfKXMUreIGQuoA1KBACu8hPQCSZclBJh5AFS0AefduoBtANbzpypoKgVQAugB8ANzEtvBKRESsVMZmFnTwJPIA7kgAFACU0YQgEvBWGfLyACagHtQAqiQAlqTpyBo4RaUwRFIAFlCU5H1NCFlEAE4%20MDEU8JxQE0mNLSTpmTmIBUVAA)

Comment: Updated the answer with the correct type: We were missing the 'constructor type'.