# Create a union type from a Record<string, number> type

Tags: typescript

We have in our codebase a Record type, for example:

```
export const Teenager: Record<string, Record<string, number>> = {
  universal: {
    thirteen: 13,
    fourteen: 14,
    fifteen: 15,
    sixteen: 16,
    seventeen: 17,
    eighteen: 18,
    nineteen: 19,
  }
}
```

Assuming we cannot change this type, how would I go about creating a new union type that only allows values `13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19`?

I have tried solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50044023/2782124). Codepen showing the offered solution not working for my use-case:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/darylshy/pen/zYyWOLG?editors=1111).

I'm not certain, but I feel that it has something to do with the `Record` type definitively defining the values as numbers, so TypeScript is accepting any number for `type Age = Teenager.universal[keyof Teenager.universal];`

Comment: You've already widened the type and lost the information. Unless you can switch to [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) (not ditching the current type entirely, but unclear if it fits within your constraints), you're stuck with `number`.

Comment: To be explicit about @jonrsharpe's statement, the type declaration `Record<string, Record<string, number>>` is what has widened the type.  Be brave and define it explicitly?  Teenager is unlike to change its range.

Comment: @CraigHicks Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately this type definition is in our codebase as a generated file. Although I may be able to talk the code owners into strengthening the type pre-generation.

Comment: I didn't mean to doubt you couldn't change it.  I meant you could just define a type with the "teen" numbers because that set of numbers is unlikely to change.

Comment: Would you like someone to write up an answer that says "no, without changing the declaration of `Teenager`, this is impossible"?